# What does this mean in pascal: const char **pzTail

Tags: delphi

I m a little lost with this declaration:

```
SQLITE_API int SQLITE_STDCALL sqlite3_prepare(
  const char **pzTail     /* OUT: Pointer to unused portion of zSql */
);
```

does it's mean :

```
out pzTail: PansiChar
out pzTail: PPansiChar
const pzTail: PAnsiChar
const pzTail: PPAnsiChar
```

NOTE: the doc of sqlite3_prepare say pzTail could be null

Comment: I would declare it as `var pzTail: PByte`.

Comment: thanks victoria, but in this way how you will pass nul ? because the doc say: "If pzTail is not NULL then *pzTail is made to ..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const pzTail: PPAnsiChar` would be the closest and most correct literal translation, especially since `pzTail` is allowed to be nil, according to the `sqlite3_prepare` documentation.

Semantically, if you never pass nil, then you should use `var pzTail:  PAnsiChar` or `out pzTail: PAnsiChar` instead.

Comment: thanks remy i was thinking the same, so it's mean that System.Sqlite.pas is wrong ;( because they declare it as out pzTail: PansiChar

Comment: @loki wouldn't be the first time the RTL has made the mistake of using `var`/`out` for a nil-able parameter. They have made that mistake for a number of Win32 API functions over the years.